# Expected 'add_filter' (T_STRING)

Tags: plugins, functions

I am trying to add a filter for get_avatar so I could implement an avatar alignment but when I do, I received **expected 'add_filter' (T_STRING**

First Approach

```
add_filter('get_avatar', 'remove_photo_class');
function remove_photo_class($avatar) {
   return str_replace(' avatar', $image_align , $avatar);
}
```

Second Approach

```
function mytheme_get_avatar( $myavatar ) {
   $myavatar = '<img class="'.$image_align.'" src="<' . get_template_directory_uri() .      '/images/authors/' . get_the_author_meta('ID', $user_id) . '.jpg" alt="' . get_the_author() . ' ">';
   return $myavatar;
}
//add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'mytheme_get_avatar' );
```

Both return the same error. Entire code can be found here in [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/tS2JbESS).

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with a class. Most everything has to be inside a class method, not counting class variables/constants.

Second, you the syntax is slightly different when adding a class method, rather than a function,  to a hook.

```
function widget( $args, $instance ) {
  add_filter('get_avatar', array($this,'remove_photo_class'));
  // the rest of your code
}
```

I would also edit your callback to remove itself:

```
function remove_photo_class($avatar) {
  remove_filter('get_avatar', array($this,'remove_photo_class'));
  return str_replace(' avatar', $image_align , $avatar);
}
```

Or explicitly remove it at the end of the `widget` method:

```
function widget( $args, $instance ) {
  add_filter('get_avatar', array($this,'remove_photo_class'));
  // the rest of your code
  remove_filter('get_avatar', array($this,'remove_photo_class'));
}
```

Or it might mess up things in other parts of the theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly put the `add_filter` hook inside a class. Considering 1st approach, put the line of code

```
add_filter('get_avatar', 'remove_photo_class');
```

inside the `widget` function. The same thing be followed for 2nd approach as well.